# Shell script, a function to verifie if FILES=$(ls) contains a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am a beginner in shell scripting and I need to find a function, to check if a variable exist in a list in bash. The list is generate this way:  `FILES=$(ls)` and so I need to check if a file is there. I am not using the `-e` test because I want to do some strange stuff with parallel by comparing two folders simultaneously, if I start to explain, it will be too long.

I've found this page  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash

I'm not sure if it is convenient in my case, because I am not sure if the `$FILES` variable that I have created is a list in the same way as the one on this page, knowing that there may by some spaces in the files names. And when I try to figure it out, the search engine shows me some stuff with -ls command that have nothing to do.

Also the problem is that I don't understand what is happening in the function that is described on that page. I am talking about the functions containing expressions like this:

```
 function contains() {
    [[ $1 =~ (^|[[:space:]])$2($|[[:space:]]) ]] && exit(0) || exit(1)
}
```

I have searched for the `=~` signification and it seems that `$a =~ $b` tests if `b`  is in `a` but than I don't know what these strange stuff `(^|[[:space:]])` and `($|[[:space:]])` means and when I try to find it on a search engine, it shows me some NASA stuff, or event if I enter something like "shell script (^|[[:space:]]) " it is just considering de word "space" and totally ignoring the symbols around, so it is showing me something that have nothing to go.

Also I don't understand why is there an "and" fallowed by an "or" without any parentheses or brackets, because these operations are not supposed to be associative.

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is considered a Bad Idea. The format changes depending on file age. it mishandles special characters in filenames. Read `man stat`.. For fun, internet search "Parsing ls Considered Harmful".

Comment: Note: `exit 0` not `exit(0)` -- shell uses whitespace to separate commands from arguments (and arguments from each other)

Comment: `[[ $a =~ $b ]]` means "the contents of $a *matches the regular expression* $b"

Comment: glenn jackman, now I see it much clearer, but in that case shouldn't there be something like ``` .* ``` before and after the ``` (^|[[:space:]])$2($|[[:space:]]) ```?

Comment: waltinator, I've tried to search about man stat, and I found this https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat  and  https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat 
I don't know if it is what you was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

`^|[[:space:]])$2($|[[:space:]]` is a regular expression. The brackets around it are useless.

- `^` marks the beginning of a string
- `|` means "either the pattern on the left side or the one on the right side"
- `[[:space:]]` is a character class that contains space and tabulator characters
- `$` marks the end of the string

Comment: Thank you four your answer. I'll go read more about regular expressions in bash.